# OkHttp: SSL Multiple POST requests generated from one call

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp on an Android project of mine in which I sync some data with a server every 15 min. The problem I encounter is that when the syncing starts, I fire an async post request using OkHttp to a secured domain and on the server side I log the requests time/data for debugging.

Checking out the log, I found out that instead of having one sync request, sometimes I have 2,3 identical requests fired at the same time with the same data.

Here is the relevant part of the class responsible for the post request:

```
public class PostClientData {
    private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public PostClientData(String baseUrl) {

         BASE_URL = baseUrl;
         client.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(false);
         client.setConnectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         client.setProxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
         client.setFollowRedirects(true);
         client.setFollowSslRedirects(true);
    }
    public static void post(String url, HashMap<String, String> postParams, Callback responseHandler) {
        String postData = getPostData(postParams);
        String absUrl = getAbsoluteUrl(url);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(PLAIN, postData);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(absUrl)
            .post(body)
            .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(responseHandler);
    }
}
```

I am using this call inside a service. The service is initiated using an alarm every 15 min. I checked out, the alarm is fired only once every 15 min. I searched and find out that maybe it can be because of failed requests, and the client retries the same request (but I added the `setRetryOnConnectionFailure (false)`).

Comment: Have you made any progress in solving this? I'm seeing the exact same scenario with basically the same concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [OkHttp interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to diagnose what's going on.